# YOUR_API_KEY not in Python code Youtube Channels:list

Tags: python, youtube-api

I'm following these instructions:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python

I have created an API key in Google Cloud Apis and Services (Api key application restrictions is set to NONE, and API restrictions set to DONT RESTRICT KEY. I have also created a OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. Both under the same project, which has YouTube Data API v3 enabled from the API library.

When I follow the instructions (link above):

In the sample that you downloaded, find the YOUR_API_KEY string and replace that with the API key that you created in step 1 of this quickstart.

That text is not present in the code (pasted below), as you can see.

What am I doing wrong!! This is the first time I've tried doing anything like this, so might be something really obvious, but I cant find the solution.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.channels.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
        id="UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm expecting to follow these instructions, but without the text YOUR_API_CODE in the script, I can't continue

From : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python

> Copy the code sample and save it in a file named example.py.
>
> In the sample that you downloaded, find the YOUR_API_KEY string and replace that with the API key that you created in step 1 of this quickstart.
>
> Run the sample from the command line. In your working directory, run:
>
> python example.py
>
> The sample should execute the request and print the response to STDOUT.

Comment: I think the API doesn't accept JSON files. It should be a key starting with 'AI----'
I have a code using the same thing and works perfectly file, if you pass the key and not the JSON. You can get it here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I followed the earlier steps and created an API and a OAUTH credentials, and then went onto the next step. In order to progress with the instructions I need the python code that I copy to have the strong YOUR_API_CODE, but its not there. So I'm not sure how to progress to Step 3?

Comment: Go to the link I sent: select project -> fo to credentials -> click create credentials -> you'll see an API key option -> click -> done

Comment: Thanks. I have the API key. Where do I paste it in that code from the Channels list ID page? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw%22%5D%7D

Comment: I'm trying to follow these instructions https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python

Comment: youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

instead of:  youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API keys are used for accessing public data so if you do a video search you don't need to be authorizated because you are accessing public data. The main point of them is to identify your application as the one making the request.

Where as methods like channels list access the channels of a user and requires oauth consent to access it.

If you are using oauth you don't need an API key as you already have identified you app with the client id.

I guess what I am saying is ignore the API key and I will report the issue to google and get the tutorial fixed.  Thanks for reporting it.